# Convert const wchar_t* to LPWSTR

Tags: c++, casting

I'm trying to convert a `const wchar_t*` to `LPWSTR` but I'm getting the error E0513.

I'm using Visual Studio with C++17.

Here is my code:

```cpp
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    LPWSTR* argv;
    int argCount;

    argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argCount);

    if (argv[1] == nullptr) argv[1] = L"2048"; <-- conversion error
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Make it an `LPCWSTR` instead? You can't assign a `const wchar_t*`  to a `wchar_t*` (unless you `const_cast`)

Comment: Not really apparently, since it was working without any problems in clion. I switched to visual studio and this error came out.

Comment: You may have used a different compiler language in CLion. A C compiler would probably accept your code. I don't know of any (modern) C++ compilers that will.

Comment: Your code is flawed. How do you know that `argv[1]` is even a valid entry in the array?

Comment: because there will be always an `argv[1]` in my program. So it will be always valid.

Comment: *So it will be always valid.* -- That's not how a good programmer writes programs.   Error checking should be done, regardless of what "guarantees" were given to you.  And even if you were given this guarantee, at the very least `assert()` that `argc` is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

You can use `const_cast`:

```cpp
argv[1] = const_cast<LPWSTR>(L"2048");
```

Or a local `wchar_t[]` array:

```cpp
wchar_t arg[] = L"2048";
argv[1] = arg;
```

However, `CommandLineToArgvW()` will never return any array elements set to `nullptr` to begin with. All array elements are null-terminated string pointers, so empty parameters would have to be specified as quoted strings (`""`) on the command-line in order to be parsed, and as such will be returned as 0-length string pointers in the array. So, you would need to check for that condition instead, eg:

```cpp
if (argCount > 1 && *(argv[1]) == L'\0')
```

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio:
C/C++ => Language => Compatibility Mode => Set to NO.

This will allow to do such casting.